# how to upload html local project on aws s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Hi I have created a project using html, css and some javascript. I have  an account in AWS, and have access to S3 service. What I want is to upload that project to AWS S3, and also want to access AWS RDS from the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since s3 hosts only static website content, the approach would be to use the api gateway for all the REST services exposed, which are consumed in the JS frameworks like Angular / React.

API gateway <--> Lambda <--> RBS / DB on EC2 
API gateway <--> ELB / ALB <--> App services running on server om EC2 / ECS

S3 hosting -> all the website html content with the above JS frameworks like angular / react where for any dynamic content, call to the Api gateway are done.

Comment: if i convert my html site into nodejs how should i upload it in s3,
if you have any link please add in your ans

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh, its not possible to use nodejs with s3 and the next best is to go for nodejs installed on ec2 behind the ELB.

Comment: Sorry i mean with ec2

Comment: Its straight forward approach, install nodejs on any flavor of ec2, apply all configurations, back it up as AMI and then attach EC2 it to ELB. And done !! use the ELB DNS to access the html files.

Comment: Thanks kartik but if i want this hall process using ubntu command, is it posibble?
i have ubuntu@ec2-**-***-***-**.ap-abc-2.compute.amazonaws.com
, .ppk file ,End point ,user name , password and webserver url

Comment: Its possible with all flavors of EC2 as long as you can install nodejs into it.